# Removing Lubuntu Splash screen from Unity/Gnome on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: plymouth

I'am running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Sony Vaio with 8GB of ram & 500Gb HDD.

I had recently installed the Lubuntu and KDE desktop environments but was not very impressed with either of them so I removed them both and went back to choosing between Unity and Gnome.

However, when I boot my computer am getting the blue Lubuntu splash screen instead of the regular default 12.04 unity screen.

How can I get rid of this Lubuntu splash screen?

Answer (score 9):

The boot splash screen is provided by the `plymouth` program, with the default theme set using the packaging system's alternatives system.

There are two ways you can change back to the default splash screen:

1. Configure the alternatives:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
   sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
   ```
2. Uninstall the theme packages from the other Ubuntu variants.  Ones to look for based on what you've described include:

   - `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo`
   - `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text`
   - `plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo`
   - `plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text`

   When removing these, be careful to check whether removing the package will cause anything else you care about to be removed.

Comment: But how did you get the package name from the terminal?

I just got the location of the .plymouth files from update-alternatives command

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the plymouth themes :

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text
```

Now the default themes should link to the ones of Ubuntu :

```
$ ls -lrt /etc/alternatives/*.plymouth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 sept. 21 01:32 /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth -> /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 sept. 21 01:33 /etc/alternatives/text.plymouth -> /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth
```