# How to completely remove Xubuntu login page?

Tags: unity, xubuntu

I have  Unity installed and later I installed Xubuntu; now I removed Xubuntu and switched back to Unity. However, every time I log in, the **there will be first the Unity login page and after logged in, it will then jump to the xubuntu login page**. So everytime I need is to tape twice  my password. How can I fix this? I tried with `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` command, but it doesn't work.

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-19-generic-advanced-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-19-generic-recovery-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-14-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-14-generic-advanced-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-14-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-14-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-14-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-14-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-14-generic-recovery-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-14-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-14-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-14-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-12-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-12-generic-advanced-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-12-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-12-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-12-generic-recovery-86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-12-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic root=UUID=86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86a4e1a4-02f7-45b8-91be-738e6c8a08f1
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

(PS: before I installed xubuntu, I modified the login theme to one of the login themes that comes with ubuntu Unity)

Comment: Login to Unity and run this: <br> `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. You will find what to remove yourself without the help of anyone (just read the lines of that file)

Comment: yes, I run this when logged in.

Comment: could you post that file to here ? run this : `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your display manager setup got messed up; I do not think that this has anything to do with the boot (grub is involved in the [splash screen selection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331973/removing-lubuntu-splash-screen-from-unity-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04), not the login).

Try this, from a virtual terminal (use ctrl-alt-F1 and log in with your user and password; ctrl-alt-F7 to go back to the graphic terminal).

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

(or if it does not work, substitute `lightdm` with `gdm`). You will have a text window; move between options with TAB and choose with ENTER --- choose `lightdm` for Unity.

Then you can restart it with

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Old (but relevant) link [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html).

If it still does not work, try to reinstall the DM:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

and/or remove gdm:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
```

(be careful with this one, if it asks you to remove important packages, do not do that --- you could end with an unusable system).

PS: Have you ever modified some file in the lightdm/gdm configuration directories, to change login background or similar things? If yes, add that info in the question,  detailing what you have done (which files you have modified/added and how).

This is because if you modify some configuration file, when reinstalling or updating, the system will not delete or reset the file you changed. So if you want to go back, you have to undo manually what you did manually...

Comment: I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` but still doesn't work

Comment: yes, before I installed xubuntu, I modified the login theme to one of login theme that comes with ubuntu Unity.